# how to handle a click event of button inside of .html file to a function inside of .ts file, in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to create an ionic2 app using a blank template. I have a button in .html which I want to link to my function Prediction() which is inside of a .ts file. I want my app to work in such a way that when I click the button, my function gets called and I get a card telling me the result of my function's calculation. The user needs to enter his/her fullname and current age.

Below is my code : For .html file

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color = "dark" text-center>
    <ion-title>
      Death Age Predictor
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>

  <ion-item required>
    <ion-label floating>Fullname</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item required>
    <ion-label floating>Current Age</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="current_age" [(ngModel)] = "current_age"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <p><button (click)="Prediction()" ion-button block>Button</button></p>

</ion-list>

<ion-card>
  <ion-card-header text-center>
    Prediction Says
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    {{ name }} will live upto {{ Prediction }} years of age.
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

for .ts file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  name = '';
  current_age;

  get Prediction()
  {
    var sum = 0;
    var name_letters = this.name.toLowerCase();
    for(var i = 0; i < name_letters.length; i++)
    {
      sum = sum + name_letters.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    var returned_age = sum % 101;
    if(this.current_age > returned_age)
    {
      var equated_age = this.current_age + returned_age;
      return equated_age % 101;
    }
    else
    return returned_age;
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you get with this code?

Comment: #suraj : In this code I am trying to create an app where a user has to enter his fullname and age. Now using 'charCodeAt' I'll sum up the char code of each alphabet in the name and modulus it by 101 in the end so that the no. comes out to be less than or equal to 100. The app is named 'Death Age Prediction' so the result would be the age upto which the user lives. Current age is required so that if the result comes out to be less than the current age, then the code can deal with it. It is just for the practice purpose as am new to ionic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a `get` in your function since your're not returning a value to something, you're manipulating values to show in your html AND you're using two-way data binding (with the `[(ngModel)]`).

So your code must be like this

```
Prediction: number; // You'll need another var for the prediction
PredictionCalculator() // Rename so it doesn't throw and duplicate error
{
  var sum = 0;
  var name_letters = this.name.toLowerCase();
  for(var i = 0; i < name_letters.length; i++)
  {
    sum = sum + name_letters.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  var returned_age = sum % 101;
  if(this.current_age > returned_age)
  {
    var equated_age = this.current_age + returned_age;
    this.Prediction =  equated_age % 101;
  }
  else
  {
    Prediction = returned_age;
  }
}
```

Since i don't know what you need to display in `{{ Prediction }}` i don't know if the logic in my code is correct. But the case is you don't have to return a value if you're not assigning it to a variable, you just need to manipulate and the assign the final value to a variable you want to display in the HTML.

Hope this helps :D

### EDIT

In your HTML you can do this

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>

  <ion-item required>
    <ion-label floating>Fullname</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item required>
    <ion-label floating>Current Age</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" name="current_age" [(ngModel)]="current_age"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>

  <p><button [disabled]="(current_age == null || current_age == '') && (name == '' || name == null)" (click)="Prediction()" ion-button block>Button</button></p> <!-- the button will be disabled until the user enters a name and a age -->

</ion-list>

<ion-card *ngIf="Prediction != null"> <!-- The card will only show when the prediction variable have a value -->
  <ion-card-header text-center>
    Prediction Says
  </ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-content>
    {{ name }} will live upto {{ Prediction }} years of age.
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

In your JS you'll just have to make sure that `Prediction` variable will receive a value, in this case, your prediction final value. I'm sorry if i didn't understand your calculations, but since you know what to do just be sure that Prediction receive a valid number.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I think I wasn't clear before. See what I need is after entering his name and age when the user clicks the button, then a card must appear below the button(on the same page) where I get the result of my calculations being made in the 'PredictionCalculator()' function.

Comment: You want the card to be hidden until the user click on the button?

Comment: @ Gabriel Barreto : In the app the user enters his fullname and age. Now using 'charCodeAt' I'll sum up the char code of each alphabet in the name and modulus it by 101 in the end so that the no. comes out to be less than or equal to 100. The app is named 'Death Age Prediction' so the result would be the age upto which the user lives. Current age is required so that if the result comes out to be less than the current age, then the code can deal with it. It is just for the practice purpose as am new to ionic

Comment: Yess I need it to be hidden. I didn't know how to do that so I left it like that initially.

Comment: updated the answer, this is the best i can do for you with what i know.

Comment: Yess it worked. Worked exactly the way I needed it to work. Thanku so so much Gabriel. Thanks a ton :):)

Comment: Hi Gabriel..
I was trying to enhance my app further by adding a background image to the app and changing the font style of the text inside the app. I tried to google it and I did get some answers to it but I found difficulty in understanding them. I wonder you could help me out here again. :)